# Rspec - Mock server running out of memory

Tags: ruby, rspec

We are using a 3rd party library that occasionally and randomly runs out of memory and will crash the app.

Is there any way for us to simulate this in Rspec?

Actually calling `exit` will actually end the test suite, and we are not aiming to test that the app has naturally called exit. Rather, we're testing that the backup mechanisms set up prior to calling the 3rd party library functioned properly.

Comment: What library are you talking about? How do you use it? What is the error message when it crashes?

Comment: It's a PDF generation library - I've raised the issue with the creators. I'm using it in the normal way.

Comment: You want to simulate a memory leak?

Comment: Re: Spickermann, when it crashes, there is seemingly no exit message?

Comment: Beyar: if this is the only possible cause of the issue, then yes?

Comment: @WillTaylor Could you briefly describe those "backup mechanisms", please? I think asking "how to simulate out of memory in RSpec" is an example of a so-called "XY problem" and the problem needs to be attacked from a different angle...

Comment: Currently I'm saving "pdf_state: ATTEMPTED" on the main model being used before running the temperamental PDF generator. I have a cron job to re-attempt odf generation on pdf_state=ATTEMPTED models.

Comment: You don't need to test the OOM crash. Test that your job/controller adds the correct `pdf_state` when the process begins. Test that job/controller updates that field when it exits correctly. And, test that the query in your cron job only fetches those items in the `ATTEMPTED` state.